# How to assert on something that is undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

this is blowing up

```
if (myObject.myKey.myThing){

}
```

> cannot read myThing of undefined

how can this be written in a way that if it is defined it goes into the if block, and if it not it does not?

Comment: Hopefully in future we will be able to use optional chaining https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining

Answer (score 0):

Add another check to see if `myObject.myKey` exists -

```
if (myObject.myKey && myObject.myKey.myThing){

}
```

Comment: yeh thought so, seems long though. but cheers

Comment: @donut you can shorten that check to `((myObject.myKey || {}).myThing)`

Answer (score 0):

you would use the hasOwnProperty method, like so

```
if (myObject.hasOwnProperty('myKey')) {
   ...
}
```

You would want to use this as opposed to just checking the value of the keys because then if the value of that key is a false equivalent value your code won't run